# Pointwise order on polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

I'm curious about the following problem. Given two polynomials $p,q:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is it possible to determine automatically if $p(x)\leq q(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$?

I assume, of course, that we are given the expressions for $p$ and $q$:
$p(x)=a_n x^n + \dots a_1 x + a_0$ and $q(x)=b_m x^m + \dots b_1 x + b_0$
with $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$.

If this is possible, is it a consequence of some general theorem that, perhaps, extends to other kinds of (commutative) abstract algebras such as, e.g., the algebra of continuous maps from $X$ compact Hausdorf to $\mathbb{R}$?

Thank you!

PS: I guess the question boils down to: is it possible to verify if $q-p\geq 0$. Sorry if the question is trivial but I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: This is what I do know: if $q-p$ is of odd degree, then it has to be zero somewhere. If it is of even degree, then there is some interval $[a, b]$ outside of which the leading term is larger in absolute value than the absolute value of all the other terms combined. If there is some zero, it has to be within that interval, so you can indeed limit your search to a compact domain.

Comment: "Automatically"? What does that mean? If it means "at once" then I don't think so: some little proof must be done, I supose...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, it is enough to consider the problem of when a polynomial $f(x) = c_n x^n + \cdots + c_1 x + c_0$ is always strictly positive.  First of all, you must have $c_n > 0$ (otherwise $f(x) < 0$ for sufficiently large $x$).  Then, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, it is enough to show that $f(x)$ has no real roots.  Any polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ factors as a product of linear factors and irreducible (over $\mathbb{R}$) quadratics.  Any linear factor corresponds to a root.  So you'll have $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ if and only if $f(x)$ is a product of irreducible quadratic polynomials (in particular, this means that the degree of $f(x)$ is even).  Thus, if you completely factor your polynomial, you can tell if it is always positive by looking at the irreducible factors.

Answer (score 0):

A real polynomial in one variable is positive if and only if it is a sum of squares of two real polynomials. A proof is given in Proposition 1.2.1 [here](http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/surv-146-prev.pdf). I'm not sure whether that leads to an algorithm for determining whether a given real polynomial in one variable is positive, but it looks like a good start.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted Alistar's answer because it seems to provide a full answer to the problem! But I find your link useful!

Comment: @RaMa2013: You could (and should) upvote an answer if you found it useful...

Comment: Yes, Alistair's answer is complete, but that "if you completely factor your polynomial" is a very big if. It may be easier to check whether it's a sum of two squares or not than to factor it. I'm not sure.